# Need antialiasing for Qml Image fillMode

Tags: image, qt, qml, antialiasing

I have a piece of code in QML:

```
Image {
    anchors.rightMargin: 10
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "Google Chrome Icon.png"
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
```

The image is automatically stretch with the window. But the stretching method is not antialiased, thus the ugly result:

[image: chrome image]

Is there any method to make the result great?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a pure QML solution you can simply set the [`smooth` property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-image.html#smooth-prop) of the `Image` element to `true`:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Image {
    smooth: true  // smoother image
    anchors.rightMargin: 10
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "Google Chrome Icon.png"
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
}
```

Comment: Qt docs say about smooth: `By default, this property is set to true.`

Comment: I have tested `smooth`, `antialiasing` and `mipmap` but not working  yet!

Answer (score 4):

you can enable Antialiasing by enabling it in `QDeclarativeView`,

```
QDeclarativeView view;
view.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
view.setResizeMode( QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView );
view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
view.show();
```

How ever to make image looks good while stretching , I will suggest you to use svg image instead of png image.